# bootstrap freelancer template theme label color overwrite not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am modifying the [bootstrap freelancer theme](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/).In the Contact me section when trying to overwrite the "Name" label's color that appears when you try to type in the name input field it appears with #18BC9C but I want it to appear with #3fcbc7. It seems its styling is coming due to a class from a parent div that changes when I click on the input inside.I tried using dev tools "Break on..Attribute modifications" but maybe I'm doing it wrong. I took the classes I saw it had and tried to overwrite it that way as its worked for the other elements but its not working here. My CSS

custom.css

```
#page-top .floating-label-form-group-with-focus{
color:#3fcbc7!important;
}

#page-top .form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls 
floating-label-form-group-with-value floating-label-form-group-with-
focus {
 color:#3fcbc7!important;
}
```

Added !important but nothing changed. Added the body id(page-top) for priority but didn't change. I don't want to edit the min css file since I heard that is considered bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `<head>` that you're calling your custom css file *AFTER* the Bootstrap CSS file. Your custom styles should be called last as the browser reads these CSS rules in order. So if your Bootstrap CSS file comes *AFTER* your custom one, it's overwriting your custom style sheet.

Comment: yea its after the freelancer.min.css

Comment: You should not write in an answer, that it is a comment, because in *Review* many people won't read any further. If you are not 100% sure if it answers the question that is ok. A comment is e.g. a question for clarification, or something like **this** comment, that is entirely non-related stuff. A imperfect answer might still be better than no anwer at all.

Comment: To ensure, your answers are not deleted, watch your language: Don't hint, it might be a *comment*, don't start with 'try'. Answer *definitive*! ;-) Read [about what is an answer, and what not.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Btw: You have 50rep now. Have fun commenting!

Comment: It was edited by you derM, to remove that I couldn't add a comment. So the collective critique of adding a comment over an answer is pointless. I acknowledged it should be a comment but I did not at the time have the privilege of adding comments. Perhaps you can take that up to the rules of Stackoverflow.com. Perhaps all this energy could have been put into helping this person out, which clearly no one has yet been able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding this **style in your index.html itself**

```
<style>
floating-label-form-group-with-focus label {
    color: #3fcbc7;
}
</style>
```

Or you can add your css which you have provided above ^^

Comment: I forgot to mention that for a brief second it seems like my light blue style takes effect and then the green takes over permanently due to js somehow i think . I added the code to index.html but its not making a difference with yours or mine.